# How to add a verbatim backslash in a newcommand?

Tags: listings

In the following example I would like to shortcut the `\lstinline` with a shorter command such as `\cd` (code). Unfortunately it does not work with backslashes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=c}
\newcommand{\cd}[1]{\lstinline{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lstinline{\ } % This works
\cd{\ } % This doesn't work

\end{document}
```

In the above example, the `\lstinline{\ }` works, but with `\cd` the backslash does not work. How to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just avoid passing the argument and define

```
\newcommand{\cd}{\lstinline}
```

Comment: Should I need the braces around `{\cd}` ?

Comment: @nowox They're not strictly necessary but are considered good `LaTeX` style.